# How do I show the random item that was generated from a list?

Tags: javascript, html

Once the "randomSong" is generated, I want it to show a sentence below like the following:

> Use the !code(my randomly generated code) command in our chat forums to redeem premium.

```js
function findSong() {
  var song = ["xikskx", "iwnujk", "ldilxb", "hgbhrw", "ijkczb"];

  var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (song.length - 1));

  document.getElementById("randomSong").setAttribute("value", song[random]);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button onclick="findSong();" type="randomSong">Generate Premium Code</button>
  <input "RandomCode" id="randomSong">
</div>
```

Comment: Please post the code needed to understand your question in your question. Also take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: please clarify your question a bit more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add `<p>` element to your html code that would be used to display the newly generated text.

```
<div>
    <button onclick="findSong();" type="randomSong">Generate Premium Code</button>
    <input "RandomCode" id="randomSong">

    <!-- new code -->
    <p id="text"></p> 
</div>
```

And then fill it on click like this.

```
function findSong() {
    var song = ["xikskx", "iwnujk", "ldilxb", "hgbhrw", "ijkczb"];

    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (song.length - 1));

    document.getElementById("randomSong").setAttribute("value", song[random]);

    // new code
    var premium = document.getElementById('text');
    premium.textContent = 'Use the code ' + song[random] + ' command in our chat forums to redeem premium.';
}
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/LLu75ksf/5/